# How to do each year calculation in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have dataframe which contains columns like **Month** and **Qty** as you can see in below table:

```
| Month    | Fruit  |  Qty   |

| -------- | ------ | ------ |

| 2021-01  | orange | 5223   |

| 2021-02  | orange | 23     |

| ......   | .....  | .....  |

| 2022-01  | orange | 2342   |

| 2022-02  | orange | 37667  |
```

I need to do sum of the **Qty** group by the **Fruit** for each **Year**. My output DF will be below table:

```
| Year | Fruit    | sum_of_qty_This_year  |  sum_of_qty_previous_year  |

| ---- | -------- | --------------------- | -------------------------- |

| 2022 | orange   |         29384         |             34534          |
| 2021 | orange   |         34534         |             93584          |
```

but there is a catch here, consider below table.

```
| current year  | jan   | feb   | mar   | apr   | may   | jun   | jul   | aug   | sep | oct | nov   | dec |      
| --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|         
| previous year | jan   | feb   |       | apr   | may   | jun   | jul   | aug   |     | oct | nov   | dec |
```

as you can see the data for mar and **Sep** is missing in previous year. So when we calculate sum of current year, **Qty** should exclude the missing months. and this should be done for each year

Comment: In other word, you need to sum Qty in each year by months from previous  year?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my draft. It needs improvement, but I think you'll understand common idea:

```
val dataDF = spark
    .read
    .option("multiline", true)
    .json("fruit.json")
    .sort("month")

  dataDF.show(100)

  val dataDFYearMonth = dataDF
    .withColumn("year", substring($"month", 1, 4))
    .withColumn("month", substring($"month", 6, 2))

  val windowSpecOrderByYear = Window.orderBy("year")

  val previousYearMonthsDF = dataDFYearMonth
    .groupBy($"year")
    .agg(collect_set($"month").as("months"))
    .sort($"year")
    .withColumn("prev_months", lag("months", 1).over(windowSpecOrderByYear))

  previousYearMonthsDF.show(10, false)

  val dataDFPrevYearMonths =
    dataDFYearMonth
      .join(previousYearMonthsDF, "year")
      .where(expr("exists(prev_months, x -> x == month)"))

  dataDFPrevYearMonths.show(10, false)

  val sumDF =
    dataDFYearMonth
      .groupBy("year", "fruit")
      .agg(sum("Qty").as("sum_of_qty_previous_year"))
      .withColumn("year_join", lag("year", -1).over(windowSpecOrderByYear))

  sumDF.show()

  val sumDFPrevYearMonths =
    dataDFPrevYearMonths
      .groupBy("year", "fruit")
      .agg(sum("Qty").as("sum_of_qty_This_year"))

  sumDFPrevYearMonths.show()


  val joinDF = sumDFPrevYearMonths.join(
    sumDF,
    sumDFPrevYearMonths("year") === sumDF("year_join"),
    "right"
  )

  joinDF.show()

  joinDF.select(coalesce(sumDFPrevYearMonths("year"), sumDF("year")), $"sum_of_qty_This_year", $"sum_of_qty_previous_year").show()
```